# What was written in John's Original letter to Amanda?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw, saw-3

In *Saw III*, Hoffman changes John's letter for Amanda with his own. Which in a way made Amanda do something which made her fail John's test.

But do we ever get any hint in any sequel/novelization or interviews that what was supposed to be in the original letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/sawspace/status/1576618202905604098) for finding out the exact letter for Amanda from John:

[image]

And the same Twitter handle was able to make it readable too:

[image]

So apparently the original letter was so sweet and might have changed the fate of multiple characters at the end of the movie.